# Link Button Not Working in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to edit a record in a CRUD application in laravel where I have a button which has been linked to go to the index view but when I click it, it redirects me to the UPDATE method of the controller.
This is my form:

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => ['players.update', $player->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'files'=>'true']) !!}

                    <div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 panel">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

                        <br />

                          <div class="form-group">
                            {{ Form::label('name', 'Player Name') }}
                            {{ Form::text('name', $player->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                          </div>

                          <div class="form-group">
                                {{ Form::label('file', 'Upload Image') }}
                                {{ Form::file('pic') }}

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                              {{Form::button('Save Record', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}
                              {!! Form::close() !!}

                              <a href="{{ route('players.index') }}">
                                <button class="btn btn-danger" >Cancel</button>
                              </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I have the following button for going back to the index page but this is taking me to the UPDATE method of the controller:

```
<a href="{{ route('players.index') }}">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" >Cancel</button>
</a>
```

This is my index method in the controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $players = Player::paginate(5);
    return view('players.index', compact('players'));
}
```

This is the UPDATE method in the controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    return "Hi";
}
```

This is my route file contents:

```
Route::resource('news', 'NewsController');

Route::resource('competition', 'CompetitionsController');

Route::resource('players', 'PlayersConroller');
```

Everything looks fine to me but I don't know what goes wrong here.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Post contents of your routes file

Comment: @AmandeepSingh, I added it to the question.

Comment: Arw you sure you have closed form tag at right place, I don't think so.

Comment: i believe your closing tag is not properly arrange.. please fix it first..

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani: did you find it as working ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will solve your issue, try to put your button code outside the form-group div.

You can change your code as

```
<a href="{{ route('players.index') }}" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
```

You can check your html you have put button inside form tag which of type submit that's why it is submitting the form again.

**Replace your form code with:**

```
<div class="row col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 panel">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

        {!! Form::open(['route' => ['players.update', $player->id], 'method' => 'PUT', 'files'=>'true']) !!}
        <br />

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('name', 'Player Name') }} {{ Form::text('name', $player->name, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('file', 'Upload Image') }} {{ Form::file('pic') }}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            {{Form::button('Save Record', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-success'])}}

        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
    <a href="{{ route('players.index') }}">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    </a>

</div>
```

Comment: What is the logic behind it?

Comment: I am posting from my mobile, so can't post code. It seems that your html code structure is not right.

Comment: @AbdulRaheemGhani : actually he is right, you can check your html you put `button` inside form tag which of type `submit` and it does the work as usual

Comment: @AmandeepSingh : I am updating code which works for him, but if he arrange his tag's properly then it will work automatically, `button` tag will work as of type `button` outside `form` tag

Comment: @AmandeepSingh : If you feel you can update/delete my changes.

Comment: @C2486 perfect. Thank you.